# Partitioning 2tb drive with windows 8 on it

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ubiquity

I have a 2 Tb HDD and I wanted to partition it about 50 GB for Ubuntu and the rest for Windows 8. But I can't seem to be able to move the slider any less  than 100 GB for Ubuntu?

[image]

PS I have already tried to do an advanced partition but I don't want to mess up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot from Ubuntu-live-disk (Ubuntu installation disk).
- Click on try Ubuntu option on startup.
- After the desktop loads, open gparted partition editor from dash.If it's not there then install it by running the below commands,

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Now open gparted partition editor.Right click on the `1862 GB` partition and select `Resize/Move option`. Make sure that all the partitions are unmounted, so that only resizing will takes place.
- Shrink it's space to get 50 GB of free space.
- Right-click on the free-space and select new option to create a new ext4 partition for Ubuntu.
- Now run the Ubuntu installer and choose something else option to install Ubuntu on the newly created ext4 partition.